# integrate $\int dx \frac{2x+1}{(x^2-9)^\frac{5}{2}}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int dx \frac{2x+1}{(x^2-9)^\frac{5}{2}}$$

$x=\frac{3}{\sin\theta}$

$dx=\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta$

$$\int d\theta \frac{\left(\frac{6}{\sin\theta}+1\right)\cdot\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}{\left(\frac{9}{\sin^2\theta}-9\right)^\frac{5}{2}}=\int  d\theta \frac{\left(\frac{6}{\sin\theta}+1\right)\cdot\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}{\left(\frac{9}{\sin^2\theta}-9\right)^\frac{5}{2}}=\int d\theta \frac{\left(\frac{6}{\sin\theta}+1\right)\cdot\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}{\left(\frac{9}{\sin^2\theta}-9\right)^\frac{5}{2}}=\int d\theta \frac{\left(\frac{6}{\sin\theta}+1\right)\cdot\frac{3\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}{\left(3\cos\theta\right)^{5}}$$

How should I continue?

Comment: Do you realize the change of variable you (seem to) want to use is actually $x=\frac3{\sin\theta}$, not $x=\frac{\sin\theta}3$?

Comment: Your substitution looks off. I'd try $x=3\sec\theta$ such that $(x^2-9) \rightarrow 9\tan^2\theta$.

Comment: @Did sorry copied it wrong form the paper

Comment: "copied it wrong f(ro)m the paper" I know. And now your $dx$ is wrong...

Comment: I don't know how much it helps, but I think you might also observe that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(x^2-9\right)^{-3/2}\right]=-\frac32\frac{2x}{(x^2-9)^{5/2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is not a continuation of your method, but rather another technique.

$\int \frac{(2x+1) dx}{(x^2-9)^\frac{5}{2}}=\int \frac{2xdx}{(x^2-9)^\frac{5}{2}}+\int \frac{dx}{(x^2-9)^\frac{5}{2}}$

For the first term, let $u=x^2-9$, making $du=2x dx$, setting the integral up for a power rule.

For the second term, let $x=3\sec u$, making $du=3\sec u \tan u$. Some trigonometric manipulation will now be necessary. Can you proceed?